# Spring Validator against numbers

Tags: spring

I have a spring form containing integer field like

```
<form:input tabindex="1" path="compAmount" id="compAmount" cssClass="controlStock"/>
```

The command class corresponding to this **form** contains the integer field **int compAmount** which binded to above text box

My Question is how we can validate this field from entering strings instead of number by user and alerting the user
**data is invalid**

Basically spring does not allow the user to submit strings by giving exception message if we give error tag

```
<form:errors path="compAmount"/>
```

Exception message is identifiable by the Developer.But it did not give normal user identifiable message eg.**data is invalid**

How can I achieve this using **Spring Validator interface**,help me

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<form:errors path="compAmount" />
```

to your jsp.

This will show the errors "attached" to this field.

Comment: But Exception message is diaplayed

Comment: So what is your problem, please descripe it better.